# Xpath : Get specific preceding siblings for each specific element

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

Here is the format of my HTML :

```
<div class="menu">
    <h3 class="menu_item_title">Title of first category</h3>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 3</div>
    <h3 class="menu_item_title">Title of second category</h3>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="menu_item">Item 9</div>
</div>
```

I want to have for each "menu_item" the H3 "menu_item_title" preceding element.
So for the first 3 elements I want to find "Title of first category" for the remaining ones I want to have "Title of second category".

In this example I have only two categories, but in reality there are much more than that.

I tried to do something like :

```
//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " menu_item ")]/preceding::h3[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " menu_items_title ")]
```

but it didnt work out.

Can someone send me some magic ;) ?

Comment: Well, I'm really sorry I didn't get the purpose of this website then. I'm sturggling with something I thought I could get some help around here. I've been browsing the website first, trying to apply topics but by the end of the day I couldn't find anything helping. So I've been presenting my problem.
But I really thought stackoverflow was a Q&A website.

Comment: @HugoTrial Please elaborate more on what you mean by *'it didnt work out'*. What the XPath currently returns and what you expect it to return instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I want to have a query which outputs 3 times : Title of first category And 6 times : Title of second category "*

That can't be done in pure XPath 1.0 only, you'll need some PHP to accomplish this task. One possible way is by executing XPath that return the `div` elements first :

```
//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " menu_item ")]
```

...then iterate through the result and execute the following relative XPath on each `div` to get the corresponding `h3` element :

```
./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " menu_item_title ")][1]
```

Comment: Thanks that's a bit what I thought.

thanks you very much for the proposal. I'll make a foreachloop and replace your [1] with [$i], I think it'll do the trick.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @HugoTrial btw, I updated the XPath to use a more specific axis `preceding-sibling` instead of `preceding`. Also, I think you don't need to replace `[1]` with `[$i]` if the xpath is *correctly* called relative to the `div` element (`[1]` returns nearest preceding sibling relative to current `div`, exactly as needed)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to get as result each `h3` element multiple times (once for each following `menu_item`) or only once, but in case of latter the following XPath

```
//div[@class='menu_item']/preceding::h3[@class='menu_item_title']
```

produces the result

```
<h3 class="menu_item_title">Title of first category</h3>
<h3 class="menu_item_title">Title of second category</h3>
```

Note that also the approach mentioned in your question will have the same result when you adjust the typo you have here: `menu_items_title` should be `menu_item_title` at the part `preceding::h3[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " menu_items_title ")]`

Comment: I want to have a query which outputs 3 times : Title of first category

And

6 times : Title of second category